# Constructing a ring with a chain of ideals $(2) \subsetneq (2^{1/2}) \subsetneq (2^{1/3}) \subsetneq \cdots$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I am trying to construct a ring that contains this chain of principal ideals: $$(2)\subsetneq (2^{1/2})\subsetneq (2^{1/3})\subsetneq \cdots$$
How can I show that it gives a ring?

Comment: Exhibit it as a subring of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I think OP wants $(2) \subset (2^{1/2}) \subset \dots$ to be a strictly increasing chain of ideals, which does not hold for $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @Dylan: I assume the intent is to get a sequence of strict inclusions (for which $\mathbb{R}$ doesn't work).

Comment: That was my guess as well, but there's no harm in spelling it out :) I'll edit.

Comment: @DylanMoreland: Sorry for the ambiguity!

Comment: @sdcvvc: I know that this is a daft question, but why does that not hold for R?

Comment: $\mathbb R$ is a field, so all the ideals $(2), (2^{1/2}), \dots$ are the same.

Comment: @Genevieve $\mathbf R$, being a field, has only two ideals: $(0)$ and $(1)$.

Comment: @sdcvvc: All that means is that we're not going to make use of the lattice of ideals of $\mathbb{R}$. *Subrings* of $\mathbb{R}$ have plenty of ideals: $\mathbb{Z}$, for example. :)

Comment: That said, it might make more sense just to give a canned example, such as the ring of algebraic integers.

Comment: Yeah, I was responding to a now deleted comment.

Comment: It might be slightly trickier to prove that this ring does what you want. Do you see how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try $\mathbb{Z}[2^{\frac12},2^{\frac13},...]$.

This is a ring, and you have strict inclusions

$(0) \subsetneq (2) \subsetneq (\sqrt{2}) \subsetneq (2^{\frac 13}) \subsetneq ...$